# Is it possible to use or attach SDD to Heroku?

Tags: heroku

We've got an application that uses local git repository to commit files received by the application. Is there a way to use local storage in Heroku for this task? We really like Heroku but we are not sure we can fit our app in it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Heroku filesystem is immutable, which means it can't write the filesystem in any way.